# Отправка данных с формы Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть html разметка с 3-мя полями для ввода :

```
<form class="form-horizontal1 m-t-md1">
<div>
  <h2>Работает?</h2>
  <div class = "form-group">
  <input class="form-control" maxlength="255" name="name" placeholder="Наименование" [(ngModel)]="name"
         #testName = "ngModel" id = "name"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input class="form-control" maxlength="255" name="number" placeholder="Номер" [(ngModel)]="number"
           #testNumber = "ngModel" id = "number"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input class="form-control" maxlength="255" type = "Date" name="date"  [(ngModel)]="date"
           #testDate = "ngModel" id = "date"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

И Angular компонент, который эту разметку реализует.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){}

  name : string;
  number : string;
  date : Date;
}
```

Как мне по нажатию на соответствующую кнопку реализовать отправку данных с этих полей на сервер и как это вообще работает? Не могу до конца понять. Сервер на java

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы выбрали Template-Driven Forms, тогда стоит заменить

```
<form class="form-horizontal1 m-t-md1">
```

на

```
<form class="form-horizontal1 m-t-md1" #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
```

Далее, в компоненте

```
public onSubmit(form: NgForm): false {
  if (form.valid) {
    // далее нужен сервис, в котором есть, например, метод create, тогда
    this.service.create(form.value);
  }
}
```

Сервис в Angular в компонентах используют следующим образом.
Шаг 1.
Создаем сервис,

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ....
```

шаг 2. В компоненте

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {}
```

шаг 3. Используем

```
// в компоненте, наш сервис доступен через this.service:

public onSubmit(form: NgForm): false {
  if (form.valid) {
    // далее нужен сервис, в котором есть, например, метод create, тогда
    this.service.create(form.value);
  }
}
```